# Implementing uniform gradient across two divs in html css

Tags: html, css, design-patterns

I created two designs in Adobe XD.

[image: Text] [image: Text]

I can achieve the first design in HTML with two divs or one div and its after etc. How do I achieve the second design in HTML and CSS?

I also want to add the border so I can't use clip-path either.

Comment: Try clip-path, you will get your result.

Comment: Well clip-path would help you. A much more complex solution would be to put a tall <div> in the background and add your gradient. Put two smaller <div> containers in front of it with a diagonal white background. Then add the two pictured <div>s on top with a transparent background and colored border - in case you need them to add some content.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.shape-border {
            width: 300px;
            height: 420px;
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0%,100% 38%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 38%);
            background-color: #000;
            padding:2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .shape {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0%,100% 38%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 38%);
            background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(237,237,237,1) 0%, rgba(49,49,49,1) 100%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="shape-border">
        <div class="shape">
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this work..